# how to enable and disable actionSet based on the perspective

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I wanted to hide the user created search item. ie search > xxx_item. This item should be enabled only to user defined perspective. Below is the actionSet used for the same. Kindly provide me feasible solution.

```xml
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.actionSets">
    <actionSet
        id="org.eclipse.search.searchActionSet1"
        label="Search"
        visible="true">

    <menu
            id="org.eclipse.search.menu"
            label="Search"
            path="navigate">
            <groupMarker name="xxxGroup"/>   
    </menu>
    <action id="com.xxx.udt.ui.MCPOpenFileSearchPage"
            definitionId="com.xxx.udt.ui.MCPOpenFileSearchPage"
            menubarPath="org.eclipse.search.menu/mcpGroup"
            label="%action.MCPFileSearch"
            icon="icons/full/search/MCPSearchDialog.png"
            helpContextId="file_search_action_context"
            class="com.xxx.udt.ui.MCPOpenFileSearchPage" >

    </action>
    </actionSet>
</extension>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `org.eclipse.ui.perspectiveExtensions` extension point for this.

In your `org.eclipse.ui.actionSets` definition of the action set specify `visible="false"` to make the action set default to not being shown.

For example this is the Eclipse debug breakpoints action set:

```xml
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.actionSets">
    <actionSet
        label="%BreakpointActionSet.label"
        visible="false"
        id="org.eclipse.debug.ui.breakpointActionSet">
```

Then specify the action set in the perspective extensions for the perspective you want to show the set in.

For example the debug break points action set is shown in the debug perspective using:

```xml
<extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.perspectiveExtensions">
  <perspectiveExtension
        targetID="org.eclipse.debug.ui.DebugPerspective">
     <actionSet
           id="org.eclipse.debug.ui.breakpointActionSet">
     </actionSet>
```

Comment: Hi Greg, I have edited the below piece of code into plugin.xml file in addtion to changing the visible ="false" in above code.But it is visible in all the perspective.<extension
      point="org.eclipse.ui.perspectiveExtensions">
    <perspectiveExtension
         targetID="com.XXX.tde.xxxPerspective">
       <actionSet
              id="org.eclipse.search.searchActionSet1">
       </actionSet>
      </perspectiveExtension>
      </extension>

Comment: If you have had the perspectives open before with the old code you will have to Reset the perspectives to make them look at the new definitions.

Comment: No i don't have any older perspective open.

Comment: No, I mean if you had them open in the past. Perspectives remember their settings and need to be reset to pick up changes. You may also need to specify '-clean' when starting the RCP to get the extension points cache rebuilt.